# Google Calendar API - Create & Share via email

Tags: google-calendar-api

All the old questions are 3-8 years out of date. Need help with V3 of Google calendar API.

1. I don't get how to specifically invite an email to the calendar from this documentation: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/acl

I see how to set the share permissions of the selected calendar, but where do we put the email that we want to share to??

Answer (score 0):

so i guess that you want to share your calendar with an email, this is my working code in python:

```
    #ACL INSERT add partecipant to a calendar
    def update_calendar_by_adding_partecipant_to_a_calendar():
        id = "mail@gmail.com"
        url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/"+ id +"/acl"

        payload = {
                  "role": "reader",
                  "scope": [{ 
                    "type": "user",
                    "value": "mail@gmail.com"
                  }]
        }

        response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
        json_response = response.text
        json_share=json.loads(json_response)
print(json_share)
```